# NFS uid mapping - reboot

Tags: mount, nfs, uid

I (as everybody )))) try to mount NFS folder on client while keeping UIDs on CentOS 6.5.

So I have user **test** with uid 10000 on server (**useradd -u 10000 -g 9999 test**), that has files belonging to him. I export folder with **no_all_squash** option.

After that I create user **test** with uid 10000 on client, mount NFS folder but **ls -ln** shows files owner 99 (nobody) **until client reboot**.
After reboot all works fine, client sees files with uid 10000. It seems that client side kernel somehow doesn't update user list/cache.
The same behavior on user delete - until reboot it shows right UIDs (though user already deleted), after reboot - 99.

Because the case in question not regular user, but system that created/deleted dynamically reboot is by no means not options. Any ideas - some config reload, etc.?

Actually what will be well is to see real UIDs on server, despite user existence on client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

can be solved by cleaning uid mapping cache on the client machines:

```
/usr/sbin/nfsidmap -c
```

you can see invalid entries in */proc*:

```
cat /proc/keys | grep 3$
```

more info about the underlying technology:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/keys.txt
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/idmapper.txt

also mentioned on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/444340/125675)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.Actually according to man "nfsidmap is used by the NFS idmapper to translate user and group ids into names", but my problem is not names themselves, but numeric UIDs.

Comment: use wireshark (tcpdump) to see what is actually going on on the network. my server was sending usernames and client was translating them.