# How to restrict user access on mounted NSFv4 share with all_squash option?

Tags: debian, nfs, uid

I have one NFSv4 server (Debian 11) and two client machines (Debian 11) which are mounting a NFS share exported by the server with `all_squash` option. I set the `all_squash` option because the two client machines have one user with same name but different UID. As addition to `all_squash` i set the `anonuid` and `anongid` option.

My Problem is that my setup works and i can write and read the files on the NFS share from clientside with the specific user, but other users on the clients have access with same rights to the files as well.

Is there a way to restrict the access to the share on clientside?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [unix.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

Comment: @tripleee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231158/nfs-uid-mapping-reboot?rq=2
doesn't look like programming question to me either.

Comment: @tripleee would you please explain in which terms my post appears to be off-topic to you?

Comment: The fact that others have posted off-topic questions in the past in no way grants you an exemption from the rules (which will have been different in 2014, too). I already pointed you to the help pages for more information, but perhaps in particular read [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic)